# Redirect с сохранением scrollTop на php

Tags: php, javascript

Возможен ли redirect на предыдущую страницу, с сохранением значения scrollTop при условии что JavaScript на странице отключен. Возможна ли реализация на php?

Answer (score 1):

Для решения вашей задачи подойдут "якоря"

http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya

**Пример использования:**

На странице есть элемент

```
 <h2 id="contents">Оглавление</h2>
```

Соответственно ссылка должна идти на страницу с хэшем `#contents`

Вида: http://yourwebsite.com/path/to/page#contents

**Живой пример на данном сайте:**

[Redirect с сохранением scrollTop на php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513460/redirect-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-scrolltop-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php/513486#513486)

Скролл перейдет на мой ответ.

---

Редирект на PHP

```
header('Location: http://yourwebsite.com/path/to/page#contents');
```